# WatiN Test: Internet Explorer not opening in windows 2008 server using Bamboo

Tags: windows, service, watin, bamboo

I am using Bamboo service to execute my tests using msbuild script. But the Bamboo service is unable to open IE on the server.

Important: I am running Bamboo as windows service. So basically IE is unable to launch through windows service.

Any sort of help will be appreciated !!

Comment: I am looking for instructions on the steps needed to run WatiN tests on windows server 2008 via Bamboo server. I am able to successfully run tests using WatiN from a console application. However, when running the tests through Bamboo server as a windows service, I encounter errors creating the internet explorer window.

Comment: The solutions that I have encountered so far include the following:(1) run the nunit tests via a batch file so that the test are run in a separate process
(2) run the service with "interact with desktop" (which I understand is a poor solution that introduces other problems)

Comment: It seems that every solution I've tried encounters a new type of exception.  First, it was a COM exception, then an IENotFoundException, then another COM exception.

Comment: Hi Ali, We're having the same problem, except with firefox rather than IE. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

We accomplish this by not running Bamboo as a service, but instead setting up the server to auto logon as a specific user, and have a startup script that runs Bamboo.  This allows Bamboo to interact with the desktop and launch the browser.

There are some registry keys that control this under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

```
AutoAdminLogin = 1, DefaultUserName = {your user}, DefaultPassword = {password}
```